# Android Studio Emulator Showing Scaled Down version of App

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

The emulator is displaying all the elements of the UI, it's just scaling everything down compared to how it is in the preview. Screenshots for clarity:

Below is how I'd like the UI to appear in the emulator:

[image]

Below is how the UI is displaying in the emulator. As you can see, the image, EditText boxes, and button do not take up the same percentage of space as they do on the preview.

[image]

Here is my XML code for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/clarksonGreen" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="577dp"
        android:layout_height="595dp"
        android:alpha="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/login_background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="266dp"
            android:layout_height="255dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/knight" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/enterEmail"
            android:layout_width="274dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textColor="@color/closeBlack"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:hint="Enter Email"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/enterPassword"
            android:layout_width="273dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="Enter Password"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/closeBlack"
            android:textColorHint="#808080" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logIn"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="274dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/clarksonYellow"
            android:text="Log in"
            android:textColor="@color/clarksonGreen"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`dp` stands for Density pixels, so parameters like `android:layout_width` & `android:layout_height` will be scaled based upon the density of the device that you are using. It may differ a little bit depending upon the screen density.

Instead of specifying a specific width & height, to elements like `ImageView` & `EditText`, apply either `match_parent` or `wrap_content` & then provide proper `margin` & `padding`. It will scale as you desire on every screen.

Reference: [Supporting Multiple Screens - Android Developers Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence)